# C++ Wrapper for TFS API

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, tfs, wrapper

I have 2 projects in VS 2012 trying to build a C++ wrapper for the Team Foundation Server API.

```
#pragma once    
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;    
using namespace System::Collections::ObjectModel;
using namespace Microsoft::TeamFoundation::Client;
using namespace Microsoft::TeamFoundation::Framework::Common;
using namespace Microsoft::TeamFoundation::Framework::Client;

namespace ManagedDll {
    public ref class  TFSAUth
    {
    public:
         TFSAUth();
        ~ TFSAUth();
        void AuthUser() 
        { 
            System::String ^x = gcnew String( "http://myhost:8080/tfs");
            System::String ^u = gcnew String( "user");
            System::String ^p = gcnew String( "Pass");
            System::Net::NetworkCredential ^c = gcnew System::Net::NetworkCredential(u, p);
            TeamFoundationServer ^something = gcnew TeamFoundationServer(x, c);
            something->Authenticate();
            System::String ^col = gcnew String (something->TfsTeamProjectCollection->Name);
            Console::WriteLine(col);        
        }
    private:
    };

     TFSAUth:: TFSAUth()
    {
    }

     TFSAUth::~ TFSAUth()
    {
    }
}

__declspec(dllexport) void Auth()
{
    ManagedDll::TFSAUth work;
    work.AuthUser();
}
```

This is the library project and I have a Test Application using this library.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "ManagedDll.h"

_declspec(dllexport) void Auth();

int _tmain()
{
    Auth();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Was all working for a while, opened this project to see if I can get any further. Today it fails to compile, giving me linker errors.

> TestApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   Auth(void)" (?Auth@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _wmain

I am not sure why as nothing has changed. But more than that, I am wondering whether I am doing the right thing while creating the C++ wrapper for TFS API.

Any help/examples/suggestions is much appreciated as this is my first attempt at a wrapper.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need C++ wrapper for TFS API?

Comment: @OlegMikhaylov I have been working on a Qt application and it has been there for a couple of years now. I wanted to add support for TFS and so I need a wrapper on the TFS API. Is there any other way? Please do suggest. It is a horrendous job to write the wrapper for a C# API I know but I feel a bit helpless. Thank you.

Comment: @VivianLobo Did this project ever get anywhere? I'm starting to look at doing something similar, found these posts, and wondered if someone has already done the work.

Comment: @KurtHutchinson I kind of gave up. It was a very long process. I switched to rest calls and it works well now.

Answer (score 0):

In your native C++ project (Test Application), you have to include the lib file of the managed C++ project (ManagedDll).

The exported DLL function in the manage C++ DLL is treated as the same as that in the native C++ DLLs, you can follow this: [Lib Files as Linker Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx) to make it work.

Also, you should remove

```
_declspec(dllexport) void Auth();
```

in the Test Application.

Comment: Thanks @Matt will keep you posted of the development.